# How can I get a JavaScript variable within my java controller using request.getparameter?

Tags: javascript, java, hibernate

I have a javascript variable within my JSP, I was wondering if there was a way I could pick this up in my java controller using the HTTP request.getparameter? This is so I can pass the string value I need into my hibernate method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two approaches - 
1.Using Form Submit
a)Define Form in JSP
b)Define Hidden field with name inside form
c)Set javascript variable value in html hidden fields (can be achieved using jquery on some event)
d)Submit form

2.Using Ajax call
a)create ajax request in jquery 
b)set javascript variable value as params of ajax.

With both approach you can access variable using request.getParameter() at server side where controller resides.

Comment: Thank you @csarathe, AJAX is the solution i'm going for!

Answer (score 2):

Java script is on browser side where java code is server side. You can not pass like this but you can do form-submission, or using URL parameter or using AJAX calls. Below is form-submission example:

**HTML:** you should wrap the hidden field insdie `<form>` tag

```
<form>
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenId" name="hiddenId"/>
</form
```

**JavaScript:**

```
document.getElementById("hiddenId").value=yourValue;
```

Then do a form submission, you will be able to get at server side using

`request.getParameter("hiddenId")`

Comment: Marking as the answer as AJAX seems to be the best approach for my web service. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can send your javascript variable value with your URI like:-

```
http://localhost:8080/myApp?myVariable="value"
```

And at server side you can simply use `request.getParameter("myVariable")` to retrieve the value of your variable.

Comment: Thank you @Vineet Tyagi, will try this also!

Answer (score 0):

```
 var value = gnval;
 $.ajax({
   method: "POST",
   url: "yoururl",
   data: {gnval: value}
 });
```

> For all those curious this is how I used AJAX to do this.